# Easiest way to create a NumPy record array from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have data like `d = [dict(animal='cat', weight=5), dict(animal='dog', weight=20)]` (basically JSON, where all entries have consistent data types).

In Pandas you can make this a table with `df = pandas.DataFrame(d)` -- is there something comparable for plain NumPy record arrays? `np.rec.fromrecords(d)` doesn't seem to given me what I want.

Comment: What kind of data structure do you want to end up with? Just an array of objects?

Comment: A NumPy [record array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), so I can do something like `pets['weight']` (which would be `[5, 20]` in this case)

Answer (score 8):

You could make an empty structured array of the right size and dtype, and then fill it from the list.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

> Structured arrays can be filled by field or row by row.
>   ...
>   If you fill it in row by row, it takes a take a tuple (but not a list or array!):

```
In [72]: dt=dtype([('weight',int),('animal','S10')])

In [73]: values = [tuple(each.values()) for each in d]

In [74]: values
Out[74]: [(5, 'cat'), (20, 'dog')]
```

fields in the `dt` occur in the same order as in `values`.

```
In [75]: a=np.zeros((2,),dtype=dt)

In [76]: a[:]=[tuple(each.values()) for each in d]

In [77]: a
Out[77]: 
array([(5, 'cat'), (20, 'dog')], 
      dtype=[('weight', '<i4'), ('animal', 'S10')])
```

With a bit more testing I found I can create the array directly from `values`.

```
In [83]: a = np.array(values, dtype=dt)

In [84]: a
Out[84]: 
array([(5, 'cat'), (20, 'dog')], 
      dtype=[('weight', '<i4'), ('animal', 'S10')])
```

---

The `dtype` could be deduced from one (or more) of the dictionary items:

```
def gettype(v):
    if isinstance(v,int): return 'int'
    elif isinstance(v,float): return 'float'
    else:
        assert isinstance(v,str)
        return '|S%s'%(len(v)+10)
d0 = d[0]
names = d0.keys()
formats = [gettype(v) for v in d0.values()]
dt = np.dtype({'names':names, 'formats':formats})
```

producing:

```
dtype=[('weight', '<i4'), ('animal', 'S13')]
```

Comment: That should work, but I was hoping for something more convenient that would figure out the data types. Guess there's nothing builtin.

Comment: `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` deduce data types from `csv` like files.  So you could write your values to a text file, and then load that.  Not that I'd recommend it.

Comment: Prior to Python 3.6 dictionaries are unordered so in earlier versions we cannot be sure that fields in `dt` and `values` will match. In my case (Python 3.5.1) `values = [tuple(each.values()) for each in d]` returns randomly `[(5, 'cat'), (20, 'dog')]` or `[('cat', 5), ('dog', 20)]`. For the latter code above fails.

Answer (score 5):

Well you could make your life extra easy and just rely on Pandas since numpy doesn't use column headers

**Pandas**

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
numpyMatrix = df.as_matrix() #spits out a numpy matrix
```

Or you can ignore Pandas and use numpy + list comprehension to knock down the dicts to values and store as matrix

**Numpy**

```
numpMatrix = numpy.matrix([each.values() for each in d])
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using pandas, and the second example doesn't retain the field names (`animal` and `weight`).

Answer (score 2):

Proposal from me (generally it's slightly improved [hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792690/easiest-way-to-create-a-numpy-record-array-from-a-list-of-dictionaries/24794783#24794783)):

`dicts = [dict(animal='cat', weight=5), dict(animal='dog', weight=20)]`

Creation od `dtype` object:

```
dt_tuples = []
for key, value in dicts[0].items():
    if not isinstance(value, str):
        value_dtype = np.array([value]).dtype
    else:
        value_dtype = '|S{}'.format(max([len(d[key]) for d in dicts]))
    dt_tuples.append((key, value_dtype))
dt = np.dtype(dt_tuples)
```

As you see there's a problem with string handling - we need to check it's maximum length to define dtype. This additional condition can be skipped if you do not have string values in your dict or if you're sure that all those values have exactly same length.

If you're looking for one-liner it would be something like this:

```
dt = np.dtype([(k, np.array([v]).dtype if not isinstance(v, str) else '|S{}'.format(max([len(d[k]) for d in dicts]))) for k, v in dicts[0].items()])
```

(still it's probably better to break it for readability).

Values list:

`values = [tuple(d[name] for name in dt.names) for d in dicts]`

Because we iterate over `dt.names` we are sure that order of values is correct.

And, at the end, array creation:

`a = np.array(values, dtype=dt)`